# Python stores " ó " as " Ã³ "

Tags: python, mysql, encoding

I use scrapy to take information from a website that according to w3 validator is utf-8..

My python project has

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

I receive some names like López J and when I print it, it shows fine...

But when I want to store it into the mysql I get some error about ascii not being able to encode blah blah blah...

If I use `.encode ('ascii', 'ignore')` i get: `Lpez J`
If I use `.encode ('ascii', 'replace')` i get: `LÃ³pez J`
if I use `.encode ('utf-8')` i get: `LÃ³pez J`

What should I do?
I'm in a big trouble here :'(

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Comments of that type are discouraged on StackOverflow.

Comment: I am trying to do that, here I am applying those solutions but with no results.

Comment: Are you connecting to mysql with the correct encoding? Try executing `SET NAMES UTF8` before you insert into the db.

Comment: @DavidRobinson oops, I didn't know that... I'm new to this, never knew I had to do that and just did.

Comment: @DanielOrtizCosta: that's OK, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @DanielOrtizCosta: Note: You do not *have* to, and any comments that nag you about it should be flagged as non-constructive. If an answer did help you, it's nice to mark it as such (you get a little rep for it too), but it is *not* required. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you connect to the database use `charset='utf-8', use_unicode=True` with other keywords to `connect()` method. This should make the dababase accept and return unicode values, so you don't have to (and shouldn't) encode them manually.

Example:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> conn = MySQLdb.connect(... , use_unicode=True, charset='utf8')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute('CREATE TABLE testing(x VARCHAR(20))')
0L
>>> cur.execute('INSERT INTO testing values(%s)', ('López J',))
1L
>>> cur.execute('SELECT * FROM testing')
1L
>>> print cur.fetchall()[0][0]
López J
```

Comment: I just did that, I still get the same problem :(

Comment: I have edited my answer to put an example. Please check it and maybe paste your code.

Comment: I don't know what is happening... I simply didn't do any .encode and they stored succesfully, but I remove the .encode to other fields I obtain using scrappy, and I get that error... why do I need that some times and some times I don0t?

Comment: I'm sorry, but if it's hard without code examples. Please make sure, you understand unicode in python (especially that you understand what are strings (bytes in py3k), what are unicode objects (strings in py3k) what is decoding and what is encoding. Read e.g. this:

http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/python-unicode-and-unicodedecodeerror

Answer (score 1):

Check your [server, database, table, column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-syntax.html) and [connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) character sets.

As a quick test, try executing

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

immediately after connecting.

Comment: What does names reffer to, the column? the database? table?
I have set all the char sets to utf8 and to utf8 general...

Comment: @DanielOrtizCosta Read the *connection* link - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: I think it is something related to python and not to mysql i've tried using java and it works...